# Log4Net works in main thread but not in created thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, unit-testing

In VS2008, C#, I've created a unit test (VS unit test) that calls some code which in turn calls Log4Net and logs some information. This works.

If I create a thread in the unit test to call the same code I'm getting **"Failed to parse config file"** exception from Log4Net.

Any ideas why it would not be able to parse the config file from the created thread but can from the main thread?

Comment: Can you post your code? How are you initializing log4net?

Answer (score 1):

Log4Net appears to use thread-local storage.

http://www.brianlow.com/index.php/2007/04/17/log4net-aspnet/